# Please Help - Misinterpreted question in UK Visa Form "how much money are you planning to spend" for a sponsored applicant

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I plan to go to the UK for a business trip with my employer bearing all the expenses during the trip.

So, What to answer the following question :

1. How much money are you planning to spend on your visit to the UK?

Is this question asking how much money that will cost to me personally (which is 0, as I will be fully sponsored), or is this just asking the estimation of cost for the whole trip (regardless who is paying)?

I've already answered it with the estimation cost of the whole trip (which is significantly higher than total amount of money in my savings/bank). As at first I assumed this may also include the cost that will be funded by the sponsor.

I have also detailed in the next questions that there will be someone paying towards the cost of my visit but, will the officer still consider my answer on the planned spending as not making any sense and refuse my application without any confirmation?

UPDATES :

I've received my passport back today with the visa issued!

So, I think both ways in interpreting the questions would work as long as you make it clear in the application form and the rest of supporting documents that the sponsor will fully cover the cost of your trip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've already submitted your application, there's not much you can do anyway except wait.

Here at Travel.SE we semi-regularly see questions from people in your situation who are confused by those parts of the application, so we can probably assume that ECOs are also familiar with the common ways to misunderstand them. If the numbers are clear enough that they can *make sense* of your application at all, it is unlikely that they'll refuse you solely for a bureaucratic mistake.

If they *can't* make sense of your numbers, you might get a refusal saying in essence "these numbers don't make sense to me". At least for the UK you'll get an individually written letter that tells you exactly what they didn't like in the application. (Some other countries reject with pithy form letters where you have to engage in a lot of guesswork). You can then immediately reapply with a clearer explanation.